# Show current environment variable in tmux pane status line

Tags: shell, zsh, tmux

I have the current git branch in an environment variable. The value of this variable can naturally change when I change the current directory. I want the value of this variable to be displayed in the current tmux pane status line (not altering the status lines of the other panes).

The following code works, but I don't like that it uses `eval` (in particular for performance reasons):

In `.zshrc` I make sure that tmux can access the variable, *and* that it is pane-specific by adding the `pane_id` value (without the `%`) in the name:

```sh
set_p10k_branch_in_tmux() {
  tmux setenv -g TMUX_${TMUX_PANE#%}_VCS_BRANCH ${VCS_STATUS_LOCAL_BRANCH:-''}
}
precmd_functions+=set_p10k_branch_in_tmux
```

In `tmux.conf` I display the variable using this setting (I inserted a newline for readability)

```
set -g pane-border-format '#(TMUX_BRANCH_VAR=TMUX_#{s/%%//:pane_id}_VCS_BRANCH; 
  eval "TMUX_BRANCH=\$$TMUX_BRANCH_VAR"; echo "${TMUX_BRANCH}")'
```

I tried to use an indirect variable reference, e.g. `echo ${(P)TMUX_BRANCH_VAR}` but I couldn't for the life of me get it to work. I made a half-hearted attempt to use an associative array, but it seemed that associative arrays didn't work inside `tmux.conf` either.

Is there a way to get this to work without using `eval`? Or is there an altogether better solution to this problem?

Comment: There are a lot of moving parts, and you may need to tweak ~/.tmux.conf to make this work, but you should be able to do `tmux select-pane -T "${VCS_STATUS_LOCAL_BRANCH:-''}"`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks, that suggestion solved my problem!